# Wait $.each untill first queue not finished

Tags: javascript, promise, jquery-deferred, deferred

---

Below is my code. if we use set timeout function we got all data but we not use we are not getting inspection data which is coming from my local db. i want use deferred and promises in my code. Thanks in advance.

```
 function onclickToCall() {

        this.$('.check-list > .check-list-box').each(function (i) {
            var j = i + 1;
            var answer_req = $(this).attr("data-isReq");
            var checklist_guid = $(this).attr("data-guid");
            var question_type = $(this).attr("data-type");
            var yes_no = $("input:radio[name='radio_" + j + "']:checked").val();
            var notes = $(this).find('#txtAreaNotes_' + j).val();
            var attachment_url = $(this).find(".txtCameraImage").attr("data-path");
            var appConfig = DriverConnectApp.State.get('config_settings');
            var item = {};
            item.checklist_guid = checklist_guid;
            item.yes_no = yes_no;
            item.attachment_url = attachment_url;
            item.notes = notes;

            if (question_type == 2) { // For Vehical visual inspection
                var dataPromise = that.getInspectionData(checklist_guid);
                dataPromise.done(function (response, vh_image) {
                    var inspectionItem = {};
                    inspectionItem.vh_url = vh_image;
                    inspectionItem.details = response;
                    item.vh_inspection = inspectionItem;
                    that.detailsArr.push(item);
                });
            } else {
                item.vh_inspection = {};
                that.detailsArr.push(item);
            }
        });
        // after finish and push all data we need to call function here
        test();
    }

    getInspectionData: function (checklist_guid) {
        var that = this;
        var deferred = $.Deferred();

        that.dbchecklist.getVehicleInspectionlist(checklist_guid, function (data, res) {
            var details = [];
            if (data.length) {
                var img = data[0].vh_image;
                var arr = JSON.parse(data[0].vh_details);
                for (var k = 0; k < arr.length; k++) {
                    var items = {};
                    items.number = arr[k].number;
                    items.notes = arr[k].notes;
                    items.attachment_url = arr[k].attachment_url;
                    details.push(items);
                }
                deferred.resolve(details, img);
            } else {
                deferred.resolve(details, img);
            }
        });
        return deferred.promise(); 
    }
```

Comment: first problem in `getInspectionData` is that resolve takes a single argument - so your `img` is not going to come through the promise

Comment: second problem is that you seem to be under the misguided but very common opinion that Promises will somehow make asynchronous code synchronous - in `onclickToCall` - `test()` will be executed before any of those promises returned in `getInspectionData` are resolved - look into using `$.when` to wait for an array of Promises - which you'll need to "build" from the `dataPromise` in each iteration of each

Comment: third problem, you use a variable called `that` in `onclickToCall` - but it's not declared anywhere

Comment: resolve takes multiple argument and its work for me also the problem is  local database field type problem. Thanks for answer and given time thanks lot. @JaromandaX

Comment: If resolve takes multiple arguments then it's not a promise